# Poor performance using rbfdot from the kernlab package in a loop

Tags: performance, r

Simplified example of my slowly working code (the function `rbf` is from the `kernlab` package) that needs speeding up:

```
install.packages('kernlab')       
library('kernlab')

rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=1)

test <- matrix(NaN,nrow=5,ncol=10)
for (i in 1:5) {
               for (j in 1:10) { test[i,j] <- rbf(i,j)}
               }
```

I've tried `outer()` but it doesn't work because the `rbf` function doesn't return the required length (50). I need to speed this code up because I have a huge amount of data. I've read that vectorization would be the holy grail to speeding this up but I don't know how.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your loops are short and you pre-allocate the result matrix, so the bottleneck is likely the `rbf` function.  You would need to profile that function to determine how (if possible) to make it faster.

Comment: There is no `rbf` function in `kernlab`.  Please double check which function you mean.  Maybe the result of, e.g., `rbf <- rbfdot()`?

Comment: try measuring the percentage of time taken up by your function (see `?Rprof`)

Comment: Indeed rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=1) (My apologies)

Answer (score 8):

If `rbf` is indeed the return value from a call to `rbfdot`, then `body(rbf)` looks something like

```
{
    if (!is(x, "vector")) 
        stop("x must be a vector")
    if (!is(y, "vector") && !is.null(y)) 
        stop("y must a vector")
    if (is(x, "vector") && is.null(y)) {
        return(1)
    }
    if (is(x, "vector") && is(y, "vector")) {
        if (!length(x) == length(y)) 
            stop("number of dimension must be the same on both data points")
        return(exp(sigma * (2 * crossprod(x, y) - crossprod(x) - 
            crossprod(y))))
    }
}
```

Since most of this is consists of check functions, and `crossprod` simplifies when you are only passing in scalars, I think your function simplifies to

```
rbf <- function(x, y, sigma = 1)
{
  exp(- sigma * (x - y) ^ 2)
}
```

For a possible further speedup, use the `compiler` package (requires R-2.14.0 or later).

```
rbf_loop <- function(m, n)
{
  out <- matrix(NaN, nrow = m, ncol = n)
  for (i in seq_len(m)) 
  {
    for (j in seq_len(n)) 
    { 
      out[i,j] <- rbf(i,j)
    }
  }
  out
)

library(compiler)
rbf_loop_cmp <- cmpfun(rbf_loop)
```

Then compare the timing of `rbf_loop_cmp(m, n)` to what you had before.

---

The simplification step is easier to see in reverse.  If you [expand](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091101135301AA2G29p) `(x - y) ^ 2` you get `x ^ 2 - 2 * x * y + y ^ 2`, which is minus the thing in the `rbf` function.

Comment: If the function truly simplifies to what you have, you could use it with `outer`.

Comment: This is quite impressive, thanks to Richie's insights I managed to realize a huge performance increase. Indeed the function simplifies to what Richie says, it looks at first sight (they give exactly the same outputn but I have to double check). This enables me to use outer() which creates the speed up.


`system.time({
test <- matrix(NaN,nrow=500,ncol=1000)
for (i in 1:500) {
               for (j in 1:1000) { test[i,j] <- rbf(i,j)}
               }
})

system.time(
test <- outer(1:500,1:1000,function(i,j) {exp(- 1 * (i - j) ^ 2)}))`

This is a speed up of 1877.333 times! (168.96/0.09).

Comment: Thanks a million Richie Cotton and Joshua Ulrich !!

Comment: Hi Richie, could you share how you come up with the simplification: from `sigma * (2*i*j - i^2 - j^2 )` to `-sigma * (x - y) ^ 2` . They  both give the same results (and the former is somewhat quicker) but I'm curious how you simplify it step by step. Could you please lay it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function kernelMatrix() in kernlab, 
it should be a couple a couple of order of magnitudes
faster then looping over the kernel function:

```
library(kernlab)

rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=1)

kernelMatrix(rbf, 1:5, 1:10)
```